# How can I create a mesh in Adobe Illustrator similar to the one shown here?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, gradient-mesh

These images are entirely composed of mesh and were created using Illustrator. I'm curious about how to produce a similarly well-aligned mesh. Could you provide guidance on this process?

Thank you.

[image: ][1]]

[image: Reference images 1 & 2]

Answer (score 4):

Create a gradient on a stroke.. then `Object > Expand Appearance`.

The result is a mesh.

[image]

Once you've expanded to the mesh, it's possible to go in and change mesh points to further refine an appearance. Which is what I suspect was done in your sample image.

---

It's also possible that your image was *not* created with Illustrator. Xara has some great mesh tools from my understanding. It's Windows-only software/ So, I've never personally used it. But I've seen many great mesh pieces from Xara users.

Comment: no illustrator at hand but cant you give these shape profiles

Comment: @joojaa yes. You can add a stroke profile to the stroke with a gradient.. then expand. Updated image to stroke with a width profile...

Comment: thank you for helping me, I successfully created the same look but my next question is how to achieve that 3d look I tried to use mesh tools and colours but this is still so hard to make such good looking vector. I would be so thankful to you if you can help me to create the same 3d vector.

Comment: There are no tricks. It's all a matter of selecting mesh points and applying the proper color to them.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a mesh is not difficult. It can be even nearly automatic as shown in the a couple of days older answer.

But filling the mesh properly for realistic (worm) look and light conditions is difficult. If you happen to have a good photo or a well rendered 3D model of the same object, you can pick the mesh node colors one by one from it. The job is difficult only, because it's a huge amount of precise tinkering. In YouTube you'll find easily examples where a realistic looking vector is colorized manually this way.

Programmers and mathematicians have tried to develop automatic tools which extract from a photo (or other bitmap image) a gradient mesh and fill it automatically. In addition the mesh is not a random one, but it's automatically matched to the apparent forms of the thing in the photo. Here's a report of one research result:

https://doi.org/10.1145/1531326.1531391

This is another (no need to be a paying member) link to the same report: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220183632_Automatic_and_Topology-Preserving_Gradient_Mesh_Generation_for_Image_Vectorization

I have never seen it implemented in in any common graphics software, though.

If you cannot buy, rent, beg, steal, borrow etc... an automatic tool and do not want to pick the mesh node colors one by one from a photo or a 3D rendering result, you have still a couple of alternatives:

1. You can fill the mesh purely based on your imagination. The amount of the work is the same as picking the colors from a raster image, but no raster image is needed, only the ability to imagine it consistently. If you happen to be able to do it, you join to the gallery of those who have got in birth something essential which is needed in making realistic paintings with traditional tools. Congratulations! I wish I were in the same league.
2. Forget the whole idea of using a gradient mesh. Draw it in a 3D program. It generates all lights and shadows automatically. The rendered result is a bitmap image, but it can be traced in Illustrator to get a vector. Only have enough colors, say 50 or more.

Having a realistic surface material and creating possible partially through the skin visible internals is not trivial. Some knowledge is needed. Even some material file must be purchased, if you cannot create 3D model materials by yourself. Material creation for 3D models is a profession by itself.

But creating the main outline geometry can be trivial. As a closing item, see this screenshot from Fusion 360:

[image]

The same seen from different direction and after an attempt to insert some color other than glossy black. Unfortunately I do not have any realistic surface materials.

[image]